# DbSet Remove method throws an exception in one-to-many disconnected scenario (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I've come across the following problem: context.DbSet.Remove() throws an exception

> *"The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."*

(not really specific case, I know) when I try to remove external login from user's logins collection. Of course, I read all similar questions, but I didn't find a satisfactory answer, unfortunately. So here I am.

There is one-to-many between User and ExternalLogin, so user can use some external logins.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    /*...*/        
    private ICollection<ExternalLogin> _externalLogins;

    public virtual ICollection<ExternalLogin> Logins
    {
        get
        {
            return _externalLogins ?? (_externalLogins = new List<ExternalLogin>());
        }
        set { _externalLogins = value; }
    }
}

public class ExternalLogin
{
    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And following relationships are discribed using FluentAPI.
For User:

```
HasMany(x => x.Logins)
                .WithRequired(x => x.User)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
```

For ExternalLogin:

```
HasKey(x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey, x.UserId });
HasRequired(x => x.User)
                .WithMany(x => x.Logins)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
```

And a method in which the exception appears:

```
public async Task<int> RemoveExternalLoginAsync(ExternalLogin el)
{
    using (var context = new MSSContext())
    {
        context.Logins.Remove(el); // just in this  line
        return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

I've read that in disconnected scenario the object should be attached firstly and then it could be removed. I tried

```
context.Logins.Attach(el);
```

But it didn't solve the problem. So I need an advice. What should I understand about EF disconnected scenario and how can I solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: I do not know how the .Remove() function works there - it **should** work with an entry in an Unchanged state - however, I've always had problems with this approach, I always set the state of the entry after attaching to deleted.

Comment: *it didn't solve the problem* Do you mean that after attaching and then removing the object you still get the same error?

Comment: @GertArnold, yes, I do. The same exception in the same line